# Naming AWS servers and creating DNS records acording to it

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I am trying to name the AWS EC2 instances with a name.

For example, an instance name is `InstanceABC` and its public IP address is 203.0.113.4, I have a domain name `example.com` and I am thinking of creating a DNS A record like `instanceabc.example.com`. This DNS record is just to identify the instance and create SSH server easily.

Will this create security issues? Or is there q better approach to identify AWS EC2 instances?

Comment: Giving it a domain name might make it slightly more visible on the internet, but doesn't really make it less secure IMHO. I just use putty and save the IP address, but if you're using a terminal a domain name can be easier, so go ahead and do that if you like.

Comment: @Tim Thanks. I was thinking the same but I still had some doubts. So, I thought of asking before implementing.

Comment: I'll convert my answer to a comment so you can accept, so others don't have to come to look at the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While giving an IP a domain name might make it slightly more visible on the internet I don't think it makes it less secure. IPs are scanned regularly by bad actor anyway.

Suggest you add a domain name if it's convenient. Make sure your server is properly secured with firewall, and updates are applied to OS and software.